# How to insert into SQLite database without affecting distinct?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using an SQLite database that holds different messaging conversations in a thread id. To get the main conversation list I use the following code:

```
database.query(true, MessagesHelper.CONVERSATION_TABLE, inboxCols, null, null, MessagesHelper.THREAD_ID, null, "${MessagesHelper.DATE} DESC", null)
```

The issue is that I provide a function to load in older messages that are not showing, by which I use:

```
database.insert(MessagesHelper.CONVERSATION_TABLE, null, values)
```

The issue is that after inserting messages, which are older than the most recent one that the distinct list used to call, it now shows the older added messages in the inbox list, which makes the list all out of order and causes a lot of confusion.

Here is the create statement:

```
private const val CONVO_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE $CONVERSATION_TABLE($NAME VARCHAR(255), $THREAD_ID VARCHAR(255), $MESSAGE_ID VARCHAR(40), $ADDRESS VARCHAR(14), $BODY VARCHAR(500), $SUBJECT VARCHAR(100), $MMS VARCHAR(255), $MESSAGE_TYPE VARCHAR(7), $MMS_TYPE VARCHAR(20), $CONVERSATION_TYPE VARCHAR(20), $GROUP_ADDRESS VARCHAR(255), $GROUP_NAME VARCHAR(255), $READ VARCHAR(10), $WHO VARCHAR(3), $COUNT INTEGER, $DATE INTEGER);"
```

Inbox columns are:

```
val inboxCols = arrayOf(MessagesHelper.COUNT, MessagesHelper.GROUP_ADDRESS, MessagesHelper.NAME, MessagesHelper.ADDRESS, MessagesHelper.READ, MessagesHelper.GROUP_NAME, MessagesHelper.BODY, MessagesHelper.DATE, MessagesHelper.THREAD_ID, MessagesHelper.CONVERSATION_TYPE, MessagesHelper.MESSAGE_ID, MessagesHelper.WHO)
```

Is there any way to insert into the database but have the distinct query still sort by each thread_id by date as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Generally, the ORDER BY must occur *after* the DISTINCT (ie. this is "wrong": `SELECT DISTINCT t.* FROM (SELECT .. ORDER BY ..) t` and the database may return records in *any order*, probably along the cluster/index used). But where is there even a distinct the above code? I am really not a fan of "hidden queries" :}

Comment: @user2864740 Interesting, that makes a lot of sense. I am on Android so unfortunately I am not sure if there is a way to write queries myself

Comment: @user2864740, the first parameter of the SQLite query method, if boolean, equates to DISTINCT. The query method builds the SQL so the initial equates to `SELECT DISTINCT columns GROUP BY column_thread_id ORDER BY date_column DESC`.

Comment: @NickMowen can you edit your question to include the table structure (the CREATE table SQL) and the code that builds the ContentValues **values**

Comment: @NickMowen could you also add the columns that make up inboxCols.

Comment: @MikeT Added that info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that DISTINCT considers the entire row being extracted, thus it is likely, based upon the column names, that both the COUNT column and the DATE column would or could likely be different when inserting a new message (e.g. perhaps count would initially be 0?) and thus cause them to be inserted as they make a new row DISTINCT (not a duplicate).

e.g. Consider this table :-

[image]

Then if DISTINCT is used just on the **idbet** column, the result is 2 rows 1 for where idbet is 3000 and another for where idbet is 1981 as per :-

[image]

However, if columns **idbet** and **gamble** are extracted then all 4 columns are extracted as there are now no duplicates, as per :-

[image]

If the row with **_id** 350 had WIN in the gamble column then 3 rows would be extracted as rows with **_id**'s 349 and 350 would be a duplicate according to the **idbet** and **gamble** columns, as per :-

[image]

Perhaps rather than DISTINCT, or just DISTINCT you should use a WHERE condition or conditions (4th and 5th parameters of query). Perhaps "count < 1" as the 4th parameter (5th null) this does assume that count will initially be 0. An alternative would be to reduce the columns extracted but that may not be practical.